# Question regarding infinite subsets of R and accumulation points

Tags: general-topology

This is a homework question but I have no clue where to get started or how to attempt this. The only one I think I know is b) which could be set $S=\{1/n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ with the accumulation point being $\{0\}$.
Any help would be appreciated!

Find an example of an infinite subset of the Reals that has

(a) no accumulation points.

(b) exactly one accumulation point.

(c) exactly two accumulation points.

(d) denumerably many accumulation points.

(e) an uncountable number of accumulation points.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it contains multiple questions together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) Can you think of a sequence of real numbers in which consecutive terms are a fixed (positive) distance apart from each other? [Hint: This is a set you are very familiar with]

(b) You are right, $\{1/n\}$ works.

(c) Modify (b). Take two sequences like that, which converge to two different points, and take their union.

(d) Extend the idea of (c) - recall that a countable union of countable sets is countable.

(e) How about $\mathbb{Q}$? Note that a sequence is just a countable set - you may not always be able to write each term out (in closed form).